# Keyboard alters weight of screen, how to avoid this on android (jetpack compose)?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have problem when the software keyboard opens I do see the screen as follows:
[image]

I have something like:

```
@OptIn(
    ExperimentalLayoutApi::class, ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class,
    ExperimentalFoundationApi::class
)
@Composable
fun ScreenScanPrint(vmUser: ViewModelUser, vm: ViewModelScanPrint) {

    val density = LocalDensity.current
   
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(lightGrayBackGround)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .navigationBarsPadding()
            .imePadding()
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(114.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            TopNavBarWithProfilePictureAndBackButton(
                text = "Αναζήτηση Προϊόντος",
                vmUser = vmUser,
                isLight = true
            )
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(24.dp)) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(120.dp),
                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = Color(0xFFF4F4FC)),
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(defaultElevation = 2.dp)
            ) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_lens_blur_24),
                        modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp),
                        contentDescription = ""
                    )
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(start = 4.dp),
                        text = "Περιγραφή",
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manrope_semi_bold)),
                        fontSize = 15.sp,
                        color = appGray
                    )
                }
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(start = 18.dp, end = 18.dp, top = 0.dp),
                    text = vm.state.productName,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manrope_regular)),
                    fontSize = 15.sp,
                    color = appGray
                )
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 18.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f))
                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom) {
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 12.dp)
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_euro_24_gray),
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp),
                            colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(appGray)
                        )
                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(start = 8.dp),
                            text = "Τιμή",
                            fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manrope_semi_bold)),
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = appGray
                        )
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier,
                        text = vm.state.price.ifEmpty { "-" },
                        fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.manrope_semi_bold)),
                        fontSize = 38.sp,
                        color = appGray
                    )
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .height(2.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(
                            appGray.copy(0.15f),
                            shape = DottedShape(step = 15.dp)
                        )
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                ItemWithIconAndText(
                    text = "Διαθέσημα Κεντρικό",
                    imageResource = R.drawable.ic_round_content_paste_24,
                    numberIs = vm.state.storeRoomCenter.ifEmpty { "-" }
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                ItemWithIconAndText(
                    text = "Διαθέσημα Αποθήκη",
                    imageResource = R.drawable.ic_round_content_paste_24,
                    numberIs = vm.state.storeRoomWarehouse.ifEmpty { "-" }
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                ItemWithIconAndText(
                    text = "Δεσμευμένα",
                    imageResource = R.drawable.ic_baseline_content_paste_go_24,
                    numberIs = vm.state.reservedProducts.ifEmpty { "-" }
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f))
                TextFieldWithIconAndButton(
                    text = vm.state.barcodeText,
                    imageResource = R.drawable.svg_barcode_white_small,
                    descriptionText = "Barcode",
                    onTextChange = { vm.onEvent(ScanPrintEvent.OnBarcodeChange(it)) }
                ) {

                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                TextFieldWithIconAndButton(
                    text = vm.state.printText,
                    imageResource = R.drawable.svg_printer_white_small,
                    descriptionText = "Εκτυπωτής ισόγειο",
                    onTextChange = { vm.onEvent(ScanPrintEvent.OnPrintChange(it)) }
                ) { }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(2f))
                androidx.compose.material.Button(
                    shape = CircleShape,
                    enabled = true,
                    onClick = {
                        vm.onEvent(ScanPrintEvent.OnScanClick)
                    },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Transparent),
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(),
                    elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
                        defaultElevation = 12.dp,
                        pressedElevation = 4.dp
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.size(84.dp)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .background(blueButtonGradient),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.svg_scanner_big_fab),
                            contentDescription = ""
                        )
                    }
                }
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in `manifest` I have set up as:             `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`
in my activity.

I would like to see the screen moving up with keyboard bellow, without altering the weights. For example when I click on `barcode`:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is `imePadding()` remove it and see result
and try use `adjustPan` in manifest

Comment: If I remove it, the keyboard appears on top of textfield...